# celery (4.x) delay() not giving desired output

Tags: python-3.x, celery

I'm following the tutorial [here](https://medium.com/@tonywangcn/how-to-build-docker-cluster-with-celery-and-rabbitmq-in-10-minutes-13fc74d21730) as I'd like to test first RabbitMQ, then encapsulate in Docker.

My structure looks like so:

```
-rabbitmq_docker
    - test_celery
        - __init__.py
        - celery.py
        - celeryconfig.py
        - runtasks.py
        - tasks.py
    - docker-compose.yml    
    - dockerfile
    - requirements.txt
```

**celeryconfig.py**

```
## List of modules to import when celery starts
CELERY_IMPORTS = ['test_celery.tasks',]

## Message Broker (RabbitMQ) settings
BROKER_URL = "amqp://admin:mypass@192.168.2.15:5672//"
BROKER_PORT = 5672

## Result store settings
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'rpc://'
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
from celery import Celery

app = Celery('test_celery')
app.config_from_object('test_celery.celeryconfig', namespace='CELERY')
```

**run_tasks.py**

from test_celery.tasks import print_statements_test, hello

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    async_result = hello.delay()
    print ("Task result hello: {0}".format(async_result.result))

    async_result = print_statements_test.delay()
    print ("Task result print_statements_test: {0}".format(async_result.result))
```

**tasks.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from test_celery.celery import app

@app.task(name='tasks.print_statements_test')
def print_statements_test():
    new_order = ['first', 'second', 'third', 'forth', 'fifth', 'sixth']
    terminal_output = []
    for i in range(len(new_order)):
        a = "This is the {0} line.\n".format(new_order[i])
        print(a)
        terminal_output.append(a)

    print ("terminal_output: {0}".format(terminal_output))
    return terminal_output


@app.task(name='tasks.hello')
def hello():
    print ("Hello there!")
```

I run `celery -A test_celery worker --loglevel=info` inside the `rabbitmq_docker` directory, and I get

```
[2019-07-09 16:25:46,702: INFO/MainProcess] Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//
[2019-07-09 16:25:46,716: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: searching for neighbors
[2019-07-09 16:25:47,754: INFO/MainProcess] mingle: all alone
[2019-07-09 17:38:54,675: INFO/MainProcess] celery@my-MBP.fritz.box ready.
```

What I don't understand is why it say `Connected to amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//` but the **celeryconfig.py** contains different info in the **BROKER_URL**?

Also in run_tasks, the tasks are called with delay(), but the resulting output doesn't show this, and just hangs on the last line (`[2019-07-09 17:38:54,675: INFO/MainProcess] celery@my-MBP.fritz.box ready.`) Why is this not being triggered?

Answer (score 0):

In your `celery.py` you have `namespace='CELERY'`.  Your `BROKER_URL` setting needs to be renamed to `CELERY_BROKER_URL`.

Comment: Thanks, I think that partly solved the issue, I since changed the prefix and now have the error: "[2019-07-10 08:16:45,176: ERROR/MainProcess] consumer: Cannot connect to amqp://admin:**@192.168.2.15:5672//: timed out.
Trying again in 2.00 seconds..."

Comment: Nope, this is not correct. Celery 4 uses `broker_url` (lower-case) configuration variable for this purpose.

Comment: @pymat are you running the worker process from within your rabbitmq docker container?  If so, are you sure it's running on 192.168.2.15?  That looks a lot like an IP you would connect to from outside the container (i.e. from your host machine to the container.)  You might want to try running your worker from outside the container and make sure that port 5672 is exposed to the host.

Comment: @Thtu I changed to CELERY_BROKER_URL = "amqp://guest@localhost//". That seemed to work. However I am trying to trigger the run_task.py script and I'm running into a circular import error, when I trigger the worker, and when I then trigger the script. I'll write another post shortly...

Answer (score -1):

As to why it says it connected to localost - Celery workers connect to `amqp://guest:**@127.0.0.1:5672//` by default if you do not specify the broker. You have used wrong configuration variable for it (BROKER_URL), when it should be `broker_url`. With version 4 of Celery, they started using the lower-case configuration variables (read more about it here: https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/userguide/configuration.html#id6 )

Similar applies for the result backend. The configuration variable should be [result_backend](https://celery.readthedocs.io/en/3.0/userguide/configuration.html#std:setting-result_backend).

If you want your run_tasks.py to block waiting for the result do the following:

```
async_result = hello.delay()
print(async_result.get())
```

Finally, do not call print() inside Celery tasks. Use the Celery logger instead:

```
from celery.utils.log import get_task_logger
LOGGER = get_task_logger(__name__)
# And use this object in your tasks...
```

Comment: from the link you sent "Celery will still be able to read old configuration files, so there’s no rush in moving to the new settings format."  -  OP has posted his config and you can see he has a namespace set for his settings.  In his configuration, it does need to be CELERY_BROKER_URL.